# Came upon SQL ORM Unmapped InstanceError while creating WTForms

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a FlaskForm and importing it to Basic.py  for the data to be added into a SQLAlchemy database for my blog.
When I try to run the codes, " Class 'builtins.str' is not mapped " came up. I was not quite sure which part of the code went wrong. Did I forget to import something?

In Form.py:

```
class AddForm(FlaskForm):

name= StringField('Provide Your Name please',  validators= [InputRequired()])
email= StringField('Provide email for identification',
                            validators= [InputRequired(), Email()])
submit = SubmitField('Join')
```

In Basic.py:

```
def JoinGroup():
form = AddForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    name= form.name.data
    email= form.email.data
    db.session.add(name)
    db.session.commit
    db.session.add(email)
    db.session.commit
    return redirect(url_for('Thank_You_Page'))
return render_template('JoinGroup.html.j2', form= form)
```

And in html file:

```
  <div class = "container">
<form method= 'POST'>
  {{form.hidden_tag()}}
  {{form.name.label}}{{form.name}}
  
  {{form.submit()}}

</form>
```

Comment: You get _strings_  from the form; you need to use this data to create model instance that you can add to the session for example `person = models.Person(name=name, email=email); session.add(person)`.

Comment: Hello @snakecharmerb. Thank you for the reply. I modified the code and checked that AddForm was imported to Basic.ppy. However, I got the error 'AddForm' object is not callable'. What could the problem be?